# How can I view/read/extract a file in .db file format?

Tags: backup, android, file-format

My phone data back up is appearing in .db file format. (Ex - contact.db, sms.db, calendar.db). Is there any way I can view/extract the data since the Restore option on my new phone is not picking up these files?

Comment: How did you create these files?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the data, and have an android device, transfer to your Android phone and download a app called SQLite editor, then find your .db files and try to open, I could open some db files on my phone